# Can home-made embeddings work for RNNs, or do they HAVE to be trained?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, word-embedding

Let's say I'm training an RNN for classification, using a vocabulary of 100 words. I can skip the embedding and pass in the sentences as one-hot vectors, but using one-hot vectors for a space of 100 features seems very wasteful in terms of memory. And it just gets worse as the vocab grows. Is there any reason why I couldn't create my own embedding where each value from 0-100 was converted into binary and stored as an array of length 7, i.e. `0=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`, `1=[1,0,0,0,0,0,0]`, ..., `100=[1,1,0,0,1,0,0]`? I realize the dimensionality is low, but aside from that, I wasn't sure if this random embedding is a bad idea since there are no relationships between the word vectors like there are with GLoVe. BTW I can't use pre-made embeddings here, and my sample size isn't huge which is why I'm exploring making my own.

Answer (score 0):

Nice logic but it is missing two important features of Embeddings.

1)We use Word Embeddings to get nearly similar vector representation of similar words.
for example, Apple and Mango will have nearly the same representation. Cricket and Football will have nearly the same representation. You might ask why is this beneficial. The answer is, Imagine we have mostly trained our Model only on Apples. If our testing has something to do with Mangos, even though we haven't explicitly trained on Mangoes, we will get an appropriate answer.

```
ex: Training: I like Apples, I drink apple juice every day.

    Testing: I like Mangoes, I drink _____ juice every day.
```

The blank will be filled with "Mango" even though we didn't train on Mangoes explicitly.
This is achieved by having a similar vector representation for both Mangoes and Apples. Which cannot be achieved by your method.

2)Don't you think even with your logic the vector will be sparse? I agree Its better in compared to One hot encoding, but not compared to Word Embeddings. 90% of word embeddings vectors aren't zeros. But in your case, it will be just 50 %.